# Skip first worksheet of the workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to have a number of worksheet on each of worksheets in a workbook skipping the first one and do some formatting as well, however i want this vba code to skip the first worksheet (name can differ but always is going to be first). Thus the question is how should i do that?

```
Sub ex2()
    Dim kl As Worksheet
    Dim Ws_Count As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Ws_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For a = 2 To Ws_Count

        With Rows("2:2")
            .RowHeight = 20
            .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 250, 230)
        End With
        With Range("B2")
            .Value = "Sheet Number" & " " & a
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
        End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: check my code in my answer below - it's 95% yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was good, you were only missing a single line, checking the current sheet `kl.Index`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ex2()

    Dim kl As Worksheet

    For Each kl In Worksheets
        ' not the first worksheet
        If kl.Index > 1 Then

            With kl.rows("2:2")
                .RowHeight = 20
                .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 250, 230)
            End With
            With kl.Range("B2")
                .Value = "Sheet Number" & " " & kl.Index - 1
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
            End With
        End If
    Next kl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub ex2()

Dim Ws_Count As Integer
Dim a As Integer


Ws_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For a = 2 To Ws_Count
    With Worksheets(a)
    'rest of your code
    End With
Next a
End Sub
```

With the posted code, the end result would be:

```
Sub ex2()
    Dim Ws_Count As Integer
    Dim a As Integer    


    Ws_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     For a = 2 To Ws_Count
        With Worksheets(a)

        Worksheets(a).Activate
        With Rows("2:2")
            .RowHeight = 20
            .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 250, 230)
        End With
        With Range("B2")
            .Value = "Sheet Number" & " " & worksheets(a).Index - 1
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
        End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work numbers from the first one. With is not changing much.

Answer (score 1):

you were almost there since you only missed worksheet `specification`

you could either add a either add a `Worksheets(a).Activate` statement right after `For a = 2 To Ws_Count` one or, which is much better, wrap your  *formatting* code in a `With Worksheets(a) ... End With` block, adding dots (`.`) before every `range` reference and have them refer to the currently referenced worksheet, as follows

```
Sub ex2()
    Dim a As Integer

    For a = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(a) '<--| reference current index worksheet
            With .Rows("2:2") '<--| reference current worksheet row 2
                .RowHeight = 20
                .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 250, 230)
            End With
            With .Range("B2") '<--| reference current worksheet cell "B2"
                .Value = "Sheet Number" & " " & a
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
            End With
        End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

So, no need for any `If` statement that would have worked only once: although it wouldn't affect performance significantly in this case it would be very inefficient from a purely *coding* point of view

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your worksheets like this, and check the index property (which stores the worksheets location) to make sure it's not the first.

```
Public Sub test()
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Index > 1 Then
        'Formatting goes here
    End If
Next
End Sub
```